# Error while sending document feed on Amazon SP-API

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to create a feed and sending an XML file in this feed.
When I'm sending the XML file, the feed process the file and the API is returning me this :

```
{
    "processingEndTime": "2022-06-28T08:12:12+00:00",
    "processingStatus": "DONE",
    "marketplaceIds": [
        "A13V1IB3VIYZZH"
    ],
    "feedId": myFeedId,
    "feedType": "POST_PRODUCT_DATA",
    "createdTime": "2022-06-28T08:10:39+00:00",
    "processingStartTime": "2022-06-28T08:10:46+00:00",
    "resultFeedDocumentId": myResultFeedDocumentId
}
```

With this response, i assume that the XML file have been successfully sended through the Amazon SP-API.

But when I'm getting the feed processing report (https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide#step-6-get-information-for-retrieving-the-feed-processing-report) it returns me this error :

`SKU 43, Missing Attributes publication_date. SKU 43 doesn't match any ASINs. Make sure that all standard product ids (such as UPC, ISBN, EAN, or JAN codes) are correct. To create a new ASIN, include the following attributes: publication_date. Feed ID: 0. For more troubleshooting help, see http://sellercentral.amazon.fr/gp/errorcode/200692370`

I searched on the doc and I couldn't find anything about the field : ***publication_date***.

Note : *I checked my XML file and I'm already sending **<LaunchDate>** and **<ReleaseDate>***.

**Here's the XML file I've sent :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>43</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ISBN</Type>
                <Value>xxxxxxxx</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <LaunchDate>2022-06-28T10:34:15</LaunchDate>
            <ReleaseDate>2013-06-17T00:00:00</ReleaseDate>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
            <ItemPackageQuantity>1</ItemPackageQuantity>
            <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>xxxxxxxx</Title>
                <Brand>xxxxxxxx</Brand>
                <MSRP currency="EUR">25</MSRP>
                <ItemType>Book</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Books>
                    <ProductType>
                        <BooksMisc>
                            <Binding>School</Binding>
                            <Language>French</Language>
                            <NumberOfPages>302</NumberOfPages>
                            <Format>standard_edition</Format>
                        </BooksMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Books>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an anwser to my question, if anyone will have the same problem as me someday.

I've got this error because my XML was **missing required information** (such as publication_date) even if the XSD wasn't giving me errors.

You can see the missing informations on your **Amazon Seller Account > Catalogue > Complete your drafts**